# What's the grammar of "Attached" in this email?

Tags: word-order, ellipsis, past-participles, correspondence

> **Attached** you will find the document "How to fill out the online application". This document gives you full details on filling out the online application and should be read with care.

They attached an document in the mail. So I could guess the meaning. But what's the grammar of **attached**? It looks like past participle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Attached you will find the document "How to fill out the online application".*

Yes, it is a past-participle. "Attached" is a preposed adjunct of place for it tells you where you will find the document. (It's preposed from end position in the sentence to the front).

The non-preposed version would be "*You will find the document "How to fill out the online application "attached”.*

Comment: Thank you for great answer. According to your answer, "You will find the document attached to this letter.” became "Attached to this letter, you will find the document." Is it okay grammatically? These both sentences are the same?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The adjunct could be re-written as "Attached to this letter" ..."

Answer (score 1):

**You will find attached** herewith (or direct object)
**Please find attached** herewith (or direct object)
**Attached you will** find herewith (or direct object)

are **set expressions** used in business (even before the internet!) to mean a document is an attachment to a letter. Nowadays, an attachment to an email or a letter, or a letter in an email.

You **attach a document to** a letter or email is a regular grammatical form in English where attach is followed by a direct object. Here,  I suspect that originally this form derives from French: **Veuillez trouver ci-joint**, as it is not a usual form in English but it widely prevalent in English business letters/communications.

When I was in my early twenties living in France, I first saw this in French and did not know it in English at all. It was only some years later that I realized it was used in English in what seems to be a direct translation. That's why I assume it originated in France and is **probably** a very old turn of phrase.

Please note that the **object comes after the verb** in this expression unlike other ways of using the verb attach in English: he attached the letter [object] to the document and mailed it out.

In a formal business letter the abbreviation Att.: [name of document attached] is placed on the left side at the end of the document.

Attached is the past participle. It is used idiomatically in this expression rather than with the usual grammar associated with an action verb: to attach something to something.

/Please find attached or enclosed/ or its variants given above would not normally even be grammatical in English. Nevertheless, the phrase has been around a long time.

Comment: So it could be, **Please find an attached document and** you will find the document "How to fill out the online application", right?

Comment: No, that is not how it is said. Sorry. If you use /Please find/, it is part of the  idiomatic expression: /Please find attached the document entitled "How to fill out the online application". NOT: /please find the attached document and etc/. These idioms must be accepted at face value in terms of usage